# wordpress pagination not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

My code is

I have written this code for pagination before my loop

```
$arrangement = get_cat_ID('arrangement');
$antiquarianism = get_cat_ID('antiquarianism');

$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

 print_r($paged);
$query = query_posts(array(

        'page'  => intval($paged),
 'category__not_in' => array($arrangement, $antiquarianism ) ));
```

every time its printing 1.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a var_dump of `$paged`? Or resetting the `get_query_var('page')` as suggested here : [worpress support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_query_varpaged-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-page-templates)

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue before. Unfortunately it could be a number of things.

One possibility is the treatment of the page query in relation to the Wordpress 'loop'. I was just reading through the documentation for query_posts and spotted this:

> Preserving the Original Query (Pagination etc.)
>   By default running query_posts will completely overwrite all existing query variables on the current page. Pagination, categories dates etc. will be lost and only the variables you pass into query_posts will be used.
>
> If you want to preserve the original query you can merge the original query array into your parameter array:

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
    array_merge(
        array( 'cat' => 1 ),
        $wp_query->query
    )
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

I'm not sure if this affects you, but it's worth shot.

EDIT: you could also try running a seperate get_post loop after 'the loop' has closed (i.e. after the main endwhile). This has solved issues for me in the past

```
<?php 
// custom pagination improvements
    //http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
     $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=50&order=DESC&orderby=ID');
     setup_postdata($lastposts);
     $valid_posts = array ();
     $lastposts = (array) $lastposts;
     foreach ($lastposts as $post) {
        $post = (array) $post;
        // Sort through arrays here - get the next valid post
        switch (true) {
            case ($post['post_status'] == 'publish' && $post['ID'] < $curr_pid[0]):
                array_push($valid_posts, $post);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
     }
     $nextArray = $valid_posts[0];
?>
 <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="next"><a href="<?php echo(get_permalink($nextArray['ID'])); ?>"><?php echo ($nextArray['post_title']); ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is some code I wrote for the front page so it would just show "next", and then link to the next post according to my filter (rather than what Wordpress thought should go next). You could of course echo out multiple links with numbers using a foreach loop. This will complicate thing a little, but it gives you very granular control over what is happening in the pagination.

Does that help you?

Comment: yaa i tried the same merging with the original query didn't give the soln instead its printing all the posts

Comment: Annoying! I'm looking at some old code now. I have added this as an edit to my original answer. What this does is perform a second get_posts after the loop is closed. Here you could specify just about anything you wanted. The only annoying thing is that you'd have to mirror this across multiple templates, so you may want to look at sticking this in a plugin if you're planning to reuse it.